# SSLV3 error while installing ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate

[image: Screen print of error]

I'm getting this error while installing the ruby gem! I tried finding gem source file but it's no use! Can you tell me how to get those certificates installed in my computer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's recommended to provide your error messages in text format, not the image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your SSL certificate files are [not up to date](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html). This [gist](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550) explains how to update them.

---

Quick steps:

1. Download cacert.pem file `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`.
2. Let Ruby know about these certificates by setting an environment variable that points to this file `SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\path\to\cacert.pem`.